# onTouchListiner & OnLongClickListener on ImageView didn't work

Tags: android, android-event

i add those `listeners` to an `imageView` like this :

```
view.setOnTouchListener(clickEvent);
view.setLongClickable(true);
view.setOnLongClickListener(longclickEvent);
```

`OnTouch` event rises and `OnlongClick` did not.
`OnlongClick` work only if i erase `OnTouch` event.

any idea please, thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple answer: You cannot have both. If you set an `OnTouchListener` all other click or long click listeners will not work anymore. If you need to use an `OnTouchListener` than you need to handle the click events manually.

Comment: Try returning `false` in your `clickEvent` (`onTouch`) implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't some `MotionEvent` to control, I recommend to you to use an `ImageButton` and set `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener`. In this case you will have the same result you are trying to have with your code, but instead, this works. The problem of use `OnTouchListener`  is that it will 'replace' the other click events. So, in the case you are doing something that can be done only with `OnTouchListener`, you can return `true` in each statement you need to be run in `OnTouchListener`, and return `false` before the last closing bracket to avoid that every touch on the screen will be handled by `OnTouchListener`.